# Communicating between a screen and a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnu-screen

I would like to write a script that starts a process in a `screen`, letting it continue to run, but extracts a certain part of the output for use in the main process of the script.

My first idea was to use a named pipe to communicate between the two processes. However, using an actual named pipe just causes the script to hang forever -- the screen boots up and runs fine, and I can access it later, but the terminal process just hangs without returning:

```
pipe=/tmp/fwdpipe$$
trap "rm -f $pipe" exit

mkfifo $pipe

server=$(cat $pipe) &

screen -dmS jupyter
screen -S jupyter -X stuff "cat foo" > $pipe\015"

wait
echo $server
```

(The background-and-wait pattern is an experiment; the problem persists if I move the `server=` line to the end.)

If I use a normal file instead, the `cat` complains that the file doesn't exist. Either way, I can't seem to achieve that original goal of communicating from within a `screen`.

Comment: I figured out part of my problem: the cat complaining that the file doesn't exist is because the screen seems to be running much slower than expected, and also running in parallel in a way I didn't expect. (I expected each `screen` line to wait for its own internal output before returning.) Simply adding `sleep 4` fixed that problem. I'd still like to use the pipe if possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should start the `screen` command before reading from the `fifo`. This example will list the current directory in `screen` and the nonexistent path error will be redirected to the fifo.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash  
  
[[ -p screen.fifo ]] \  
|| mkfifo -m 660 screen.fifo  
  
exec 3<>screen.fifo

session=test  

screen -ls $session >&- || screen -dmS $session  
screen  -S $session \  
        -X stuff 'ls \$PWD nonexistent 2> screen.fifo\n' &  
  
while IFS= read -r -u 3; do  
echo REPLY: $REPLY  
done
```

You can also use `tee` to write to both `screen` and the fifo:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

[[ -p screen.fifo ]] \
    || mkfifo -m 660 screen.fifo

session=test

screen -ls $session >&- || screen -dmS $session
screen  -S $session \
        -X stuff "printf '%s\\\n%s\\\n' hello world | tee screen.fifo\n"

text="$(cat < screen.fifo)"
echo "$text"
```